# Why does using slice notation work for copying lists but not other sequences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, slice

If I want to copy a list object I can do the following:

```
colours = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow']
colours_copy = colours[:]
```

However when I do the same with a string and compare IDs both variables seem to be pointing to the same object:

```
string = 'lion'
new_string = string[:]
print(id(string))
print(id(new_string))
```

Output:

```
2397445995824
2397445995824
```

Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably because strings are immutable, whereas lists are mutable. You can try the same with tuples.

Comment: @j1-lee `np.array`s are mutable but `[:]` will not return a copy. I don't think there is any convention about what `[:]` should or shouldn't do on a particular object type, and it's up to the developer to choose the effect of the operation, and up to the user to read the docs...

Comment: Why does it matter, why do you care about the id of a string?

Comment: (Note in example above with `np.array`. `[:]` will return a different id object but of a *view* of the same data...)

Comment: @Julien Good observation!

Answer (score 1):

These are some optimizations made by Cpython. For immutable objects like string , tuple and so on, shallow copies of them will get themselves. It often have no impact on users, isn't it?

Note, though, that if there are mutable objects in the tuple, the shallow copy will get themselves, but the deep copy will get a new object:

```
>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> a is a[:]
True
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> a is deepcopy(a)
True
>>> a = ({1, 2},)
>>> a is a[:]
True
>>> a is deepcopy(a)
False
```